# When flipping a coin, the probability that there are i more heads than tails

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider successive independent flips of a coin that lands on "head" with probability p. Let h(k) and t(k) denote respectively the number of heads and tails in first k flips. Let $i\in \{1,2,..\}$ and T(i) denote the first time when there are i more heads than tails, i.e., 
$$
T(i)=max\{n:h(k)<t(k)+i, \forall 1\leq k\leq n-1\}.$$
Find the probability $$
\mathbb{P}(T(i)=2n+i|h(2n+i)=n+i).
$$
and furthermore, find the probability
$$
\mathbb{P}(T(i)=2n+i).
$$

Here is my attempt: I have seen the Bertrand's ballot problem (see the wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem ) in the course and I try to use the result from that problem so I do the following:
$$
T(i)=max\{n:n+i-h(k)>n-t(k), \forall 1\leq k\leq n-1\}.
$$
and then consider $p=n+i-h(k)$ and $q=n-t(k)$, but then I figured out that the cases are somehow different and we might need to count from back (???).
Then I tried the combinatorics method and find that the total possibilities might be given as the sum of $
i+2k-2 \choose k
$$i+2k \choose 2n-2k$ but the sum seems hard to calculate. 
I think that the first method might be the correct approach, can someone help me?